# Clearing Cassandra cqlsh console in Windows

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

How can we clear the cassandra cqlsh console in Windows. I tried all from clean, clear, cls, cls().

Thanks in advance.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clearing a terminal is typically a function of the terminal application itself, not the program running within it.

For example in a bash shell you can do 'CTRL+L' to clear the screen, even when in an interactive console like cqlsh.   In a Windows command prompt, as far as I know there is not an option for doing this within a program, you would have to terminate the program and execute 'CLS' to clear the screen.